# Is Regex the only way to search HTML for certain text combinations or can I use XPath in this case?

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I have read there's a way to use regex with xpath in php 5.3+ but I don't have that version and cannot upgrade for certain reasons.

So what I want to know if there's a way I can achieve the following using Xpath or should I just stick to regex. I want to be able to check if an HTML document contains/matches some of the following:

- `{Powered by|Script Source:|....} <a href='some-domain.com'>Text 1|Text 2|...</a> [e.g. should match: Powered by <a href='http://wordpress.com'>Wordpress</a>`
- `<img src='....' alt='img-[0-9]-[a-zA-Z].(jpg|png)'>`
- `<script src='contains particular script'>`

Is there any way to achieve any of the above conditions through an xpath query and while not compromising on speed and efficiency?

Comment: Is [the Simple HTML DOM project](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) what you are after?

Comment: I checked that out but couldn't figure how to execute a search to find the first or second combinations I mentioned

Comment: The manual is at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm if that would help.

Comment: That's what I had checked, no solution or illustration to the kind of search I'd want to make to at least find a match for condition #1 that I mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a PHP script with [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net):

[Example](http://shaquin.tk/experiments/htmldom-test.php).

I have put the code and result on that page.

The strings/URLs/`src`s can be put in an array.

As it cycles through an array, it tests for the link `href` and content, the `script` `src`, and matches the `img` `src` with a regular expression.

Comment: That was useful, very useful indeed! It gave me a much better perspective on how to use simple html dom, I've only used the regular php dom and xpath till date. However, any ideas how I could use this to search for "Powered by <a href='http://www.wordpress.com'>Wordpress</a>". Yes, you've given a function that will find the link wordpress.com but any quick way of knowing whether the text "Powered By" precedes that link. Is there any "before" or "after" functionality in simple html dom?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_traverse_traverse): Scroll down to 'How to traverse the DOM tree'. `parent` gets the parent, e.g. `$link->parent`. Note: You have to use `$html->find('a', 0)` instead of `$html->find('a')`. I will work on a solution when I find the time.

Comment: @Sam: Not all WordPress site have the `Powered by Wordpress` message, but they do have a `generator` meta tag. Could that be searched for instead?